# How to map custom/dynamic requests to a controller (Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How can I map custom/dunamic requests toa given controller, based on a repository lookup?

The use-case is a CMS-like feature in a web-platform, where certain URL patterns ("pages") stored in the DB should be handled by a separate controller `PageController.java`. These patterns are not necessarily known at compile-time, and they can also be added and modified while the app is deployed (thus, it cannot be annotation-driven).

I did try to map a controller to "**" (see below), but that did not work for 2 reasons: firstly all other requests resolved to that same controller method (I had hoped that it would use "**" as a fallback and try the others first), and it also ended up resolving all requests to my static/asset files to this controller (resulting in unwanted 404-responses).

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @Inject
    private PageService pageService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @CurrentUser User user) {
        String path = request.getRequestURI();
        Page page = this.pageService.getByPath(path, user);
        if (page == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        return "web/page";
    }
}
```

The temporary work-around/modification to the above method has so far been to map a pre-defined URL-prefixes to this controller (eg. `/page/**`, `/info/**`, `/news/**` etc), but this is an inelegant solution that adds arbitrary limitations to the system which I now seek to eliminate.

I am currently using Spring Boot 2.0. In addition to the naive mapping to `**` in a regular `@Controller` class (using the `@RequestMapping` -annotation), I have also tried configuring `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` the following way:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Inject
    private PageDao pageDao;

    @Bean
    public PageController pageController() {
        return new PageController();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping pageUrlHandlerMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping pageUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        PageController pageController = this.pageController();
        Map<String, Object> urlMap = this.pageDao.findAll().stream()
                .map(Page::getNormalizedSlug)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                        slug -> pageController, (existing, duplicate) -> existing));
        pageUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);
        pageUrlHandlerMapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE); // <- Cannot be LOWEST_PRECEDENCE for some reason...
        return pageUrlHandlerMapping;
    }
}

public class PageController implements Controller {

    @Inject
    private PageService pageService;
    @Inject
    private DmaWebControllerAdvice controllerAdvice;

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        User user = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof User) {
            user = (User) principal;
        }
        String path = request.getRequestURI();
        Page page = this.pageService.getByPath(path, user);
        if (page == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("web/page");
        modelAndView.addObject("page", page);
        controllerAdvice.globalModelAttributes(modelAndView.getModel(), null);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

This approach does technically work, but the list of pages will somehow have to be reloaded into the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping whenever one of the pages is changed (i am not quite sure how to do that). This also possibly overwrites some default Spring Boot-configuration, that I would ideally like to keep. It also has some drawbacks compared to resolving controllers using `@Controller` and `@RequesMapping` because I currently am injecting certain data into all views resolved that way (mainly model-data used in the overall design of the website, like menu, quicklinks etc). In the above attempt, I have had to set those via a separate call to `controllerAdvice-globalModelAttributes()`.

What I am seeking is a solution where my repository is queried for potential page-matches in runtime, and if it is valid then the request will be handled by the proper page-controller. Is a custom HandlerMapping -implementation the way to do this? And if not, how should I solve this? And if making a separate HandlerMapping for pages, how do I add/register this in my configuration without overwriting the default provided by Spring?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just implement a catch-all controller which parses your patterns as a parameter, does a db look-up and then use a [forward](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward) to specific controllers (info, page, news etc.)? Seems like for a CMS, this look-up logic belongs into your code (e.g. service layer).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest(but not the best) way to achieve what you need is creating custom `HandlerMapping` implementation:

```
public class PageMapper implements HandlerMapping, Ordered {

    private HandlerMethod handlerMethod;        

    public CustomMapper(Object controller, Method method) {
        this.handlerMethod = new HandlerMethod(controller, method);
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerExecutionChain getHandler(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws Exception {
        return new HandlerExecutionChain(handlerMethod);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE; //you have to add the handler to the end
    }     
}
```

Now remove `@Controller` annotation from `PageController` because you don't need it to be detected automatically anymore. After that register controller and mapping to config:

```
@Configuration
public class AppWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public PageController pageController() {
        return new PageController();
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping pageMapping(PageController pageController) {
        Method method = BeanUtils.resolveSignature("getPage", PageController.class);
        return new PageMapping(pageController, method);
    }
}
```

Now every request unrecognized by other `HandlerMapping` instances will be sent to your mapping hence to your controller. But this approach has obvious disadvantage. Since your mapping is the last in the chain of mappings you never get 404 error. Therefor you never know about something wrong with you resources (e.g. if some of them are missing).

I would prefer let application to distinguish paths by prefix (just like you do it already), where prefix is operation application is going to do with a page. For example if you need to show or edit the page:

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    private final static String SHOW = "/show";
    private final static String EDIT = "/edit";

    @Inject
    private PageService pageService;

    GetMapping(value = SHOW + "/**")
    public String getPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @CurrentUser User user) {
        String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(SHOW.length());
        Page page = this.pageService.getByPath(path, user);
        ...        
        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        return "web/page";
    }

    //the same for EDIT operation
}
```